# Automatic login after clicking on link

Tags: reactjs, authentication, popup

Is it possible to automate authentication after clicking on link in react app that opens new website (other web app which I am not developing) which opens and asks for username and password in form of login pop-up dialog. So I don't have to write username and password and user of the application don't have to know credentials after clicking on link. [login pop-up dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMJO1.png)

Comment: Hi Simo, it is possible, what you are looking for are called "magic links", there are services that can help you to build a nice authentication user flow using magic links and other features like passwordless authentication. I'd recommend you to check [this service](https://www.ownid.com)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @VictorNavarro. I solved problem by adding credentials inside link  http://<username>:<password>@<rest of the link>. Now I have problem with hiding my credentials

Comment: that's definitely a bad practice. You should never put the credentials on the link. Instead, you should use a token. It is quite complicated to be developed in a secure way, I'd recommend again to look for a service.